# transition probability matrix between the metastable states

Tags: python, matrix, probability, markov-models, nest-dynamic-modules

I have calculated the transition matrix of a Markov state model with four metastable states. I would like to know the probability of transition between metastable states, for which I think I should obtain a 4x4 matrix.

I have tried to obtain said matrix with this code, but it turns out that in some entries of that matrix values ​​greater than 1 appear, which seems strange to me:

```
nstates = 4
transition_matrix_meta = np.zeros((nstates, nstates))
for i in range(nstates):
    for j in range(nstates):
        
        pi_i = msm.pi[msm.metastable_sets[i]].sum()
        
          T_i_to_j = msm.transition_matrix[msm.metastable_sets[i]][:, 
                  msm.metastable_sets[j]]
        
        
        P_i_to_j = pi_i * T_i_to_j.sum()
        
        
        transition_matrix_meta[i, j] = P_i_to_j



print(transition_matrix_meta)
```

Is my code correct?

Answer (score 0):

Your code appears to be on the right, but there might be a normalization issue.

This modification ensures that each row of transition_matrix_meta sums to 1

```
nstates = 4
transition_matrix_meta = np.zeros((nstates, nstates))

for i in range(nstates):
    for j in range(nstates):
        pi_i = msm.pi[msm.metastable_sets[i]].sum()
        T_i_to_j = msm.transition_matrix[msm.metastable_sets[i]][:, msm.metastable_sets[j]]
        P_i_to_j = pi_i * T_i_to_j.sum()
        
        transition_matrix_meta[i, j] = P_i_to_j

# Normalize the rows
transition_matrix_meta = transition_matrix_meta / transition_matrix_meta.sum(axis=1, keepdims=True)

print(transition_matrix_meta)
```

Comment: Dear Oyinlade Demola, Shouldn't the diagonal of this matrix contain only 1's? It means the probability of transition of a state in the same state.

Comment: Yes, that's correct. Normalizing the transition matrix ensures that the diagonal elements are exactly 1

Comment: The matrix is         0                   1             2             3
                      0  0.964480  0.014320  0.000000  0.021200
                      1  0.007681  0.988989  0.000000  0.003330
                      2  0.000000  0.000000  0.988291  0.011709
                      3  0.003580  0.000170  0.004396  0.991854, the question is, Aren't the probabilities of transition from one state to another very small?

Comment: it appears that the probabilities are relatively small, which is common in Markov chains.it just means they have high probability of staying in thesame state. Please there is a typo in my previous comment it is the sum of rows that needs to be 1

Comment: Dear Oyinlade Demola, thank you. Is the probability of transition from one state to the same state always high? I have calculated the stationary probabilities of the metastable states. What is the relationship between the values ​​of the diagonal of the previous matrix and the values ​​of the stationary probabilities?This is the code:                                                     
nstates = 4     
msm.pcca(nstates)
for i, s in enumerate(msm.metastable_sets):
    print('π_{} = {:f}'.format(i + 1, msm.pi[s].sum()))